# Increasing click area for UIBUTTON

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton that i declared as custom
I want to increase its tap area so that the clickable area is increased without affecting the image set into it as setImage.
How can i efficiently do that that . This is my code . It does not work but not can not think of a efficient solution.

```
let btn = UIButton (type: .custom) 

   btn.bounds.insetBy(dx: 20 , dy: 20)
```

Comment: Is the goal to make the button itself larger? If so, you need to tell us how you are giving it size in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change a UIButton's Content, Title, and Image Insets in UIButton's Size Inspector. You can adjust these attributes directly with Swift as well.

Another "hacky" option would be to put the image in a separate UIImageView, and then place a button (with a transparent background) in front of it. That way, from the user's perspective, the button will appear to have that image, but the sizes of the image and "clickable area" are now independent from one another.